# Raise DataGrid ItemCommand event from Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, datagrid

I am using a DataGrid to display data retrieved from a database and I was wondering if it is possible to raise the grid's ItemCommand event using Javascript.

The snippet below shows roughly what I am trying to do within onclick handler for the DIV removeProductButton. I don't want to use asp:Button or asp:LinkButton as currently the look and feel of the DIV is controlled using CSS and the code should work regardless of the type HTML element used to create the click-able trigger to allow for future look and feel customisations.

```
<asp:datagrid id="itemGrid" runat="server" cellPadding="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="items">
                    <div class="product_title"><%#Eval("ItemID")%>.&nbsp;<%#Eval("ItemDescription")%></div>
                    <div class="product_image">
                        <img id="productImage_<%#Eval("ItemID")%>" src="<%#Eval("ThumbnailURL")%>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <div id="removeProductButton" class="buttonStandard" onclick="Do Something HERE...">Remove</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:datagrid>
```

I have tried using the following code in the grid's ItemCreated event but was not able to get it working

```
private void itemGrid_ItemCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        dynamic itemData = e.Item.DataItem;

        HtmlGenericControl removeProductButton = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("removeProductButton");

        removeProductButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(removeProductButton, ""));
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hidden button to the ItemTemplate with your desired CommandName:

```
<asp:Button 
    ID="removeProductButton_hidden" 
    runat="server" 
    style="display:none;" 
    CommandName="YourCommandName" 
    Text="" />
```

Make sure that your 'Remove' div has the runat="server" attribute:

```
<div ID="removeProductButton" runat="server" class="buttonStandard">Remove</div>
```

Get rid of the grid ItemCreated handler and create a grid ItemDataBound handler that looks like this:

```
public void grd_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl removeProductButton = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("removeProductButton");

        Button removeProductButtonHidden = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("removeProductButton_hidden");

        removeProductButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(removeProductButtonHidden, ""));
    }
}
```

So the entire grid definition would look like this:

```
<asp:DataGrid 
    runat="server" 
    ID="itemGrid" 
    OnItemCommand="itemGrid_ItemCommand" 
    OnItemDataBound="itemGrid_ItemDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button 
                    ID="removeProductButton_hidden" 
                    runat="server" 
                    style="display:none;" 
                    CommandName="YourCommandName" 
                    Text="" />
                <div class="items">
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <div ID="removeProductButton" runat="server" class="buttonStandard">Remove</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for help Kevev22, it worked a treat but I have decided to bite the bullet and replace the DIV with an ASP Button to keep things simple.